# Wait for Http calls Angular 4 ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.cdsDataService.getServersForComponent().map(one => this.Servers = one),
    this.cdsDataService.getComponentForServer().map(two => this.Components = two))
    .subscribe(res => {

        //for these ids more http calls are made 
        for (let comp of this.Components) {
            this.compIds.push(comp.ID);
            //does not wait for this http call to complete
            this.getObjectsById();
            SomeMethod();
        }}
    );

getObjectsById()
{
    let observableBatch = [];
    this.compIds.forEach((key) => {
        observableBatch.push(this.cdsDataService.getComponentLinks(key).subscribe(p => {
            //console.log(key);
            for (let it of p) {
                let nodelink = {from: key, to: it.ID, color: "blue"};
                this.componentLinkData.push(nodelink);
            }
            // console.log(p);
        }));
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
}
```

`getComponentForServer()` returns ids that are used by `getObjectsById()`

`getObjectsById()` loops through ids and makes http calls for each id.

I am not able to make the program wait for all the calls from `getObjectsById()` to finish.
It simply jumps to `SomeMethod()`;

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially doing a `subscribe()` inside a `subscribe()`. Because `http` calls are asynchronous, the code just executed without waiting for the result.

Use `switchMap` or `concatMap` instead:

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.cdsDataService.getServersForComponent(), this.cdsDataService.getComponentForServer())
    .switchMap(([servers, components]) => {
        let observableBatch = components.map(comp => this.cdsDataService.getComponentLinks(comp.ID)
            .map(p => {
                this.componentLinkData = p.map(it => ({from: comp.ID, to: it.ID, color: "blue"}))
            }));
        return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch)
    })
    .subscribe(()=>{
        SomeMethod();
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

you are subscribing to each request instead of subscribing to `forkjoin`.

```
this.compIds.forEach((key) => {
    observableBatch.push(this.cdsDataService.getComponentLinks(key));
});

return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe((p: any[]) => {
    //console.log(key);

    for (let it of p) {
        let nodelink = { from: key, to: it.ID, color: "blue" };
        this.componentLinkData.push(nodelink);
    }
    // console.log(p);
});
```

Comment: even then it is still not waiting..http call loads data but the diagram is drawn before the data is completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.cdsDataService.getServersForComponent().map(one => this.Servers = one),
  this.cdsDataService.getComponentForServer().map(two => this.Components = two))
).switchMap(() => {
  return Observable.forkJoin(this.Components.map(c => {
    return this.cdsDataService.getComponentLinks(c.ID).tap(links => {
      links.forEach(link => {
        let nodelink = {from: c.ID, to: link.ID, color: "blue"};
        this.componentLinkData.push(nodelink);
      });
    });
  }));
}).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('I am done!');
  SomeMethod();
});
```

Not using pipable syntax as your original code is not.